# Read table metadata from a batch of MS-Access databases

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 70+ Access databases in a directory. I think that some of them are forks of other databases in the same directory. A way to detect them is to check creation times of tables, but this way I need to open files and tables one by one and write down creation time.

Is there an easy way to automate this? Is there a way to read creation time of the tables of a batch of Access files?

Comment: I asked the same question 10 days ago at superuser.stackexchange https://superuser.com/questions/1606206/read-table-metadata-from-multiple-microsoft-access-databases . Since I got no answers I try here.

Comment: Yes there is way. Where do you want to show the results then?

Comment: Anywhere. I just want to use them myself. In a text file, an Access table or just in the screen would be good.

Comment: Please try my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DAO to loop the TableDefs within a database, and get this information. Something like the below should get you started:

```
Sub sCheckAll(strPath As String)
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = Dir(strPath)
    Do
        If (Right(strFile, 3) = "mdb") Or (Right(strFile, 5) = "accdb") Then
            Call sTableDefCreateTime(strPath & strFile)
        End If
        strFile = Dir
    Loop Until strFile = ""
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sCheckAll", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
Sub sTableDefCreateTime(strDBPath As String)
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Set db = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase(strDBPath)
    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        If Left(tdf.name, 4) <> "MSys" Then '   exclude system tables
            Debug.Print tdf.name & vbTab & tdf.DateCreated & vbTab & tdf.Connect
        End If
    Next tdf
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sTableDefCreateTime", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

It also gets the connection string, as some of the tables may be linked.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Use following codes to get file names and created date of files from a directory. This will show result to a excel sheet like column `File Name` and column B `Created Date`.

```
 Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim strDir As String
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    strDir = "D:\TEMP\"
    i = 1
    
    StrFile = Dir(strDir)
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Cells(i, 1) = StrFile
        Cells(i, 2) = myMetaData(strDir & StrFile)
        StrFile = Dir
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub

Function myMetaData(CheckingFile As String)
    Dim fs As Object, f As Object
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(CheckingFile)
    myMetaData = f.DateCreated
End Function
```

Comment: This only gives the information for the database itself, not the tables within the database.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but if I'm understanding it well, that code gets creation date of files while I need creation date of tables inside those files. In MS-Access you can manually get creation data of each table by viewing its properties. I just want to see creation dates of all tables in all databases in the same directory.